# Chi-Square goodness of fit test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

i got the following task (im gonna translate everything so forgive me any mistakes):

A hunter is hunting wolves and taking notes on how many time he misses a shot before killing the wolf.
The table shows how many times he missed (shooting 100 ($n$) wolves)

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline \text{amount of missed shots} & 0 & 1 & 2 & >2 \\ \hline \text{empirical frequency} & 72 & 18 & 8 & 2 \\ \hline  \end{array}

My job is to check if the amount of missed shots is geometrically distributed with $p=0.7$ for an level of significance of $\alpha = 0.05$

I wanted to use a $\chi^2$ goodness of fit test but i didnt know how to 
properly choose my $H_o$ and $H_1$

What i did so far is:

Calculating the probablities for the geometrical distribution:
$$P(X=0) = 0.7 ; \\
P(X=1)= 0.21;\\
P(X=2)= 0.063;\\
P(X\gt2)=0.027;\\$$

I also read that for approximation with the $\chi^2$ distribution one has to make sure that $np_i$ $\gt5$  ∀ $i$ so i summed up the last two probabilities to $P(X\ge2)=0.09$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H_0$: Amount of missed shot is geometrically distributed with $p = 0.7$

$H_1$: Amount of missed shot is not geometrically distributed with $p = 0.7$

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline \text{amount of missed shots} & 0 & 1 & 2 & >2 \\ \hline \text{empirical frequency} & 72 & 18 & 8 & 2 \\ \hline \text{expected frequency} & 70 & 21 & 6.3 & 2.7\\ \hline \end{array}

$$\chi^2  = \frac{(72-70)^2}{70} + \frac{(18-21)^2}{21} + \frac{(8-6.3)^2}{6.3} + \frac{(2-2.7)^2}{2.7} \approx 1.1259$$